# How I can use react 0.13 with ES6 syntax on old project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have old jquery-like project. Our team start to develop new feature and I would like to use React 0.13 on this. I put scripts into site folder (react.0.13.min.js, JSXTransformer.js) and below put my app.react.js

How I can write some test code, in this case?
I try to type:

```
'use strict';

class Story extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var story = this.props.story;
    return (
      <View>
        <Image uri={story.author.profile_picture.uri} />
        <Text>{story.author.name}</Text>
        <Text>{story.text}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

From Chrome debugger I can access to React variable. What I need to do?

Comment: Have you included your script and the JSX transformer script properly? There's an example: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/displaying-data.html

Comment: @WiredPrairie you right, but in this example, they don't use ES6 class syntax. May be I need to load another script for this?

Comment: You'll need to precompile it. You could use something like Babel. Be warned that if you're supporting older browsers, that it may not work or you may need shims.

Comment: You almost always need shims, but there are some unsolvable problems on IE8 if you need to support that.  Also your code example looks like react-native, make sure you're on the right site.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand it's not react-native. it's from - https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/19/building-the-facebook-news-feed-with-relay.html and you right - I need shims.

Answer (score 2):

I solve my problem. If you have old project, you can do this:

1) Install gulp/grunt babel

2) Write task for precompile ES6 to ES5, like this for gulp:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var babel = require("gulp-babel");

gulp.task("default", function () {
  return gulp.src("app/assets/react/app.react.jsx")
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("app/assets/javascripts/"));
});
```

3) link for React lib files:

```
<script src="http://fb.me/react-0.13.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.1.js"></script>
```

4) Enjouy ES6 syntax and React power ;)

Comment: You can remove jsx-transformer.  Babel does the jsx transform for you.